# Swipe particular part of layout and swipe back

Tags: android, layout, swipe

I am creating a calculator app in android.Just like a modern calculator you see in your android device. I have created a `TextView`and below that, all my buttons are present.I also want to include the `trignometric` functions so when buttons layout is `swipped`, i want to show `trignometric` function and when it is swiped back it show numeric buttons.The TextView should remain constant at the top.Can you somebody please guide me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes u can do it.
here is an example how to do it

Layout Example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <!-- Static content -->
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/holo_blue_light"
    android:orientation="vertical" />

  <!-- ViewPager Indicator -->
  <com.viewpagerindicator.LinePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/view_pager_indicator"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/ll_bottom"
    android:background="@color/holo_orange_light"
    app:lineWidth="10dp"
    app:selectedColor="#fff"
    app:strokeWidth="10dp"
    app:unselectedColor="#888888" />

  <!-- ViewPager containing fragments with different views -->
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/view_pager_indicator"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/holo_red_light" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: ViewPager]
 In the blue region you place your static content which doesn't change like the 
 The orange region is used by the 
 ViewPagerIndicator and finally the red region is the one of the ViewPager. this area is swipeable.

Comment: Where should i put my Numeric View and trignometric View

Comment: at the last child of relative layout that is **<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>**